# How to insert multidimensional array data in react js?

Tags: javascript, json, multidimensional-array, reactjs

Here, i have included a my example code. If it is one dimensional array means, i can easily insert json data's into my code. How to achieve this one with multidimensional json data with react js?

```
var Category = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
        <div>
          {this.props.data.map(function(el,i) {
            return <div key={i}>
                <div>
                    {el.product}
                </div>
                <div>
                    {el.quantity}
                </div>
            </div>;
          })}
        </div>
    );
  }
});

var data = [
    {
        product:"a",
        quantity:28,
        sub:[
            {
                subItem:'a'
            },
            {
                subItem:'b'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        product:"b",
        quantity:20,
        sub:[
            {
                subItem:'a'
            },
            {
                subItem:'b'
            }
        ]
    }
];


React.render(<Category data={data}/>, document.body);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create component for sub categories like this,

```
var SubCategory = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    var list = this.props.data.map(function(el, i) {
      return <li key={i}>{ el.subItem }</li>;   
    });

    return <ul>{ list }</ul>;
  }
});
```

and use it in `Category` component

```
{this.props.data.map(function(el,i) {
  return <div key={i}>
    <div>{el.product}</div>
    <div>{el.quantity}</div>
    <SubCategory data={ el.sub } />
  </div>;
})}
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/22728/)

Comment: thanks for your quick response. And also i need one more help. How to read data from web servers?

Comment: @Sathya add ajax call to componentDidMound handler where you need change state with new data - like this https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/22731/. only replace in this example ajax call to you method that does ajax call - like in jquery $.ajax